# Nesting filters and functions in twig | Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.4

I have this simple question. Can i nesting filters in twig, using syfmony2?

Imagine i need to do the following in twig:

```
{{ custom_function(var)|filter1|filter2 }}
```

Also i need respect the order. The "filter1" filter output, has to be the "filter2" filter input.

---

Example:

`{{ getPrice(var)|formatPrize(2,'.')|prizeSymbol('$') }}`  prints: $ 12.25

`{{ getPrice(var)|formatPrize(3,',')|prizeSymbol('u$s') }}`  prints: u$s 12.251

---

The above requirement is useless, but i need to do something like this.

I know how to make the twig extension, but not how to solve nesting.

I apologize for my english, Google Translate did the hard work :-)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Filters can be chained as per the documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#filters)

E.g.

```
{{ name|striptags|title }}
```

Comment: Please add the necessary information for answering this question to your answer, so nobody has to leave to an external resource to get his answer. Linking for additional information or as a prove is perfectly fine though.

Comment: Thanks, I had not found it in the twig documentation. Sorry about that, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Of course filters can be chained, as @Richard wrote. For you as the extension author, there is nothing you have to pay attention to. Your filter code gets input – regardless of whether it’s the only filter, or if (for example) it’s the 4th filter in a chain of 5 filters.